# How to use update_fields in django signals post_save

Tags: django

I hope my title is enough to understant what i am trying to say if not then sorry in advance.

I dont have problem on inserting data, but how about when the admin update the section of student were the student have already record?, I just want to update the current data not add another data

this is my code in my model.py(post_save)..

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
def create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Courses=instance.Courses, Sections=instance.Section)
    if created and teachers.exists():
        StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
            # This should be the instance not instance.Student_Users
            Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
            # The below is also not an instance of SubjectSectionTeacher
            Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.first())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has other problems (why are you using CamelCase for attributes?), but in Django if you want to *conditionally* create a new object, you can use [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create). Example:

```py
StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create(
        pk=instance.pk, defaults={"enrollment_credits": enrollment_credits}
)
```

This will create a new `StudentsEnrolledSubject` object if `instance.pk` does not exist in the database. Otherwise, it will update the existing instance's `enrollment_credits`.

Comment: where did you get that enrollment_credits? sorry for the late reply